# React + React query Pagination only re-render on window focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pagination, react-query

I am using React-Query with react, Now I am trying to do pagination but the component only renders on window focus. It is illustrated in the following video,

[image: Illustration]

Here we can see that the component only re-renders only after the window focus on how to fix that. Below is the code for the components,

The Query Hook,

```js
// To get all the chats Details
export const useGetChats = ({
  userId,
  jwt,
  params,
}: {
  userId: number;
  jwt: string;
  params: {
    perPage: number;
    page: number;
    sortBy: string;
  };
}) => {
  // Query Key
  const queryKey = ['users', userId, 'chats'];

  // Response
  type ResponseType = IChat[];

  // Fetcher
  const fetcher = async () => {
    const QueryUrl = `/api/v1/users/${userId}/chats?perPage=${params.perPage}` +
    `&page=${params.page}&sortBy=${params.sortBy}`
    return await axios.get<ResponseType>(QueryUrl, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` }
    });
  };

  // Query
  return useQuery(queryKey, fetcher, { keepPreviousData: true });
};
```

The Chat View (List the chats),

```
interface IChatViewProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  setSortBy   : (shortBy: "name" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt") => void;
  sortBy      : "name" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt";
  isFetching  : boolean;
  onPrev?     : () => void;
  onNext?     : () => void;
  hasPrev     : boolean;
  hasNext     : boolean;
  chats       : IChat[] | null;
  onDelete?   : (chat: IChat) => void;
  onOpen?     : (chat: IChat) => void;
  onEdit?     : (chat: IChat) => void;
}


// Chat View
export default function ChatView({
  isFetching,
  setSortBy,
  sortBy,
  hasPrev,
  hasNext,
  chats,
  onPrev,
  onNext,
  onDelete,
  onOpen,
  onEdit,
}: IChatViewProps) {
  // sort change handler
  const handleSortChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<"name" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt">) => {
    setSortBy(event.target.value as typeof sortBy);
  }

  // if chats are loading
  if (chats === null) {
    return <CircularProgress sx={{margin: "auto"}}/>;
  }

  // select Component for the sortBy
  const SelectSort = (
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
      <InputLabel id="sort-by-label">Sort By</InputLabel>
      <Select
        onChange={handleSortChange}
        labelId="sort-by-label"
        value={sortBy}
        label="Sort By"
        id="sort-by-select"
      >
        <MenuItem value={"createdAt" as typeof sortBy}>
          Created At
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"name" as typeof sortBy}>
          Name
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"updatedAt" as typeof sortBy}>
          Updated At
        </MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )

  // chats component to render
  const UserChats = chats.map((chat: IChat) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <HorizontalBar
          onDelete={onDelete}
          onOpen={onOpen}
          chat={chat}
          onEdit={onEdit}
        />
        <ChatDivider />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });

  // fetching status
  const Fetching = isFetching ? (
    <CircularProgress
      sx={{margin: "8px auto 0 7px"}}
      size={"1rem"}
    />
  ) : (
    null
  );

  // render
  return (
    <ChatViewWrapper>
      <Header>
        <Title>Your Chats List</Title>
        {Fetching}
        <Sort>{SelectSort}</Sort>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        {UserChats.length === 0 ? (
          <NoChats>No Chats</NoChats>
        ) : (
          UserChats
        )}
      </Body>
      <Footer>
        <Button disabled={!hasPrev || isFetching}
          variant="outlined"
          onClick={onPrev}
        >
          Prev
        </Button>
        <Button disabled={!hasNext || isFetching}
          variant="outlined"
          onClick={onNext}
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </Footer>
    </ChatViewWrapper>
  );
}
```

The Dashboard,

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  // sort by state
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState<"name" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt">("name");

  // page number
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);

  // user details
  const user: IUser | null = useSelector(selectUser);

  // jwt token
  const jwt: string | null = useSelector(selectJwt);

  // if no user throw
  if (!user || !jwt) {
    throw new Error("No User found");
  }

  // chats for the dashboard
  const {
    isPreviousData : isPrevData,
    isError,
    data,
    error,
    isFetching,
  } = useGetChats({
    userId: user.userId,
    jwt: jwt,
    params: {
      page: pageNumber,
      perPage: 5, // it is a constant
      sortBy: sortBy,
    },
  });

  // if error throw
  if (isError) {
    throw new Error("Error in getting chats: " + error);
  }

  // Header Link
  const link = data ? data.headers["link"] : undefined;

  // on prev handler
  const onPrev = () => {
    setPageNumber(Math.max(pageNumber - 1, 0));
  }

  // on next handler
  const onNext = () => {
    if (!isPrevData && link?.includes("next")) {
      setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
    }
  };

  // body
  const Body = () => (
    <DashboardWrapper>
      <UserView
        onDelete={() => null}
        onEdit={() => null}
        user={user}
      />
      <ChatView
        onDelete={() => null}
        onOpen={() => null}
        onEdit={() => null}
        isFetching={isFetching}
        setSortBy={setSortBy}
        sortBy={sortBy}
        onPrev={onPrev}
        onNext={onNext}
        hasPrev={pageNumber > 1}
        chats={data?.data || null}
        hasNext={!isPrevData && link?.includes("next") || false}
      />
    </DashboardWrapper>
  );

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
      <Body />
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I removed Css and some stuff But the complete code is available at [github](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/Chatviewer/tree/v2) Thank You

Comment: Query key should include every parameter that you use inside your fetcher, including `page` in your case and all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query key doesn't include all dependencies that you are also using in the query function. React-Query will only automatically trigger a refetch if the queryKey changes. This is documented in multiple places:

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#treat-the-query-key-like-a-dependency-array

Answer (score 0):

pass `refetchOnWindowFocus: false` option to useQuery like this:

```
 return useQuery(queryKey, fetcher, 
{ 
  keepPreviousData: true,
  refetchOnWindowFocus: false 
});
```

also you can use [react-query-useful-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query-useful-hooks), so that you don't have such problems.