# Server side pagination is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, mern, react-query

I am developing a MERN stack app where I am trying to implement server side pagination.

Note that I am using React Query for managing server state.

On the root route, I display two posts.

[image]

When I click on the `Next` button, **NEXT** two blog posts should be displayed. However, this is not happening. I see the same two posts on page 2 as on page 1.
[image]

Where is the problem?

I think, there is either some problem with my server side pagination logic or with React Query. I suspect React Query is not fetching blog posts when I click on the `Next` button; instead it is fetching the posts from the cache. (I could be wrong here).

These are my code snippets:

postControllers.js

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const Post = require("../models/postModel");

const fetchAllPosts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { pageNumber } = req.body;
  const pageSize = 2;
  const postCount = await Post.countDocuments({});
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(postCount / pageSize);
  const posts = await Post.find({})
    .limit(2)
    .skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1));
  res.json({ posts, pageCount });
});
```

postRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");

const { fetchAllPosts, createPost } = require("../controllers/postControllers");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/api/posts", fetchAllPosts);

module.exports = router;
```

Posts.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useFetchAllPosts } from "../hooks/postsHooks";
import Spinner from "../sharedUi/Spinner";

const Posts = () => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useFetchAllPosts(pageNumber);

  const handlePrevious = () => {
    setPageNumber((prevPageNum) => prevPageNum - 1);
  };
  const handleNext = () => {
    setPageNumber((prevPageNum) => prevPageNum + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : isError ? (
        <p>{error.message}</p>
      ) : (
        data.posts.map((post) => (
          <p className="m-6" key={post.title}>
            {post.title}
          </p>
        ))
      )}
      <div>
        {isLoading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : isError ? (
          <p>{error.message}</p>
        ) : (
          <div className="flex justify-between m-6 w-60">
            <button
              disabled={pageNumber === 1}
              className="bg-blue-400 px-1 py-0.5 text-white rounded"
              onClick={handlePrevious}
            >
              Previous
            </button>
            <p>{data.pageCount && `Page ${pageNumber} of ${data.pageCount}`}</p>
            <button
              disabled={pageNumber === data.pageCount}
              className="bg-blue-400 px-1 py-0.5 text-white rounded"
              onClick={handleNext}
            >
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

postHooks.js

```
import { useQuery, useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export const useFetchAllPosts = (pageNumber) => {
  const response = useQuery(["posts"], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/posts", pageNumber);
    return data;
  });

  return response;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React + React query Pagination only re-render on window focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73321059/react-react-query-pagination-only-re-render-on-window-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all dependencies of a query (= everything that is used inside the query function) needs to be part of the query key. React Query will only trigger auto fetches when the key changes:

```
export const useFetchAllPosts = (pageNumber) => {
  const response = useQuery(["posts", pageNumber], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/posts", pageNumber);
    return data;
  });

  return response;
};
```

to avoid hard loading states between pagination, you might want to set `keepPreviousData: true`

see also:

- [the official pagination example](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/examples/react/pagination)
- [the guide on paginated queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/paginated-queries)

Comment: Why you answer duplicated questions multiple times? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73321059/react-react-query-pagination-only-re-render-on-window-focus